# Maveryx for Installed applications

Tags: java, selenium, automation

I want to open installed applications in windows based system automatically and perform different tasks. Just like selenium do for web based tasks. Does Maveryx handle installed applications?

Comment: Where's the code?

Comment: I do not have code. Just want to know Maveryx can deal with applications other than java and android or not.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for questions related to programming. To find out about a certain tool or library please look elsewhere.